# For Firestore listeners using a conditional query, how do I get updates when a document change means it no longer passes the query condition?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say I have a collection of tasks with a `dateCompleted` field. I want a query to display a list of completed tasks completed today in an app. I want to use a listener so that the list automatically updates when changes are made to the list.

```js
const today = "2023-05-02";
db.collection("tasks").where("dateCompleted", "==", today)
  .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      /* insert data into app */
    });
  });
```

Then let's I have a document where `doc.dateCompleted` is `today`, but I update it so `doc.dateCompleted` is `yesterday`. The problem is that the new document no longer satisfies the query condition, and so the listener doesn't receive the updated document. As a result, the app continues to show the document in the "completed today" list because it is unaware that the document has changed.

There are a few solutions I can think of, none are perfect:

1. Listen for all documents in the collection and filter the data client-side. But that's not optimal for database reads, particularly as the number of documents in the collection gets large.
2. Update the local data on the client when making the document change. This might be a reasonable solution, except for when the document change occurs somewhere else (e.g. on server, or on another device). If the task list is shared by multiple users, this becomes a problem.
3. Add an additional `dateModified` field to fetch documents that have been changed today, and then merge that data with the original query. This is far better than option 1, but it will still result in duplicate reads.

Are there any other solutions to this that might be better than these? I feel like this is a pretty common situation with listeners, so I'm wondering if I'm missing an obvious solution or best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to respond to the specific changes that happen to each document, which you can do by looping over `querySnapshot.docChanges` (instead of looping over the snapshot itself as you do now.

From the Firebase documentation on [viewing changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots):

> It is often useful to see the actual changes to query results between query snapshots, instead of simply using the entire query snapshot. For example, you may want to maintain a cache as individual documents are added, removed, and modified.
>
> ```
> db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
>     .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
>         snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
>             if (change.type === "added") {
>                 console.log("New city: ", change.doc.data());
>             }
>             if (change.type === "modified") {
>                 console.log("Modified city: ", change.doc.data());
>             }
>             if (change.type === "removed") {
>                 console.log("Removed city: ", change.doc.data());
>             }
>         });
>     });
> ```
>
> Important: The first query snapshot contains added events for all existing documents that match the query. This is because you're getting a set of changes that bring your query snapshot current with the initial state of the query. This allows you, for instance, to directly populate your UI from the changes you receive in the first query snapshot, without needing to add special logic for handling the initial state.

So when you check `docChanges` in your scenario of changing the date, you'll get a `change.type === "removed"` for the document once it falls outside of the query.

Comment: Frank, thanks for the reply. I tried your solution, and while I can see the document where `change.type === "removed"`, the document itself still contains the old data `doc.dateCompleted === today` and not the updated data `doc.dateCompleted === yesterday` which is what I need.  I suppose I could do something where `if(change.type === "removed")` then fire off an ad hoc firestore query just the removed items, but that seems a bit hackish. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Hey Frank, I just realized another solution: I can use the  `change.type === "removed"` condition to remove the document from the app's local state so that the local state accurately reflect the updated doc and not the old data. Probably the cleanest solution. But it would appear that the way firestore works is that when a document is updated to fall outside of the listener query, the retrieved document reflects the old data, and not the updated data, correct? Is that by design? It would seem better to retrieved the updated document.

Comment: #1) I indeed would not expect you to get up-to-date data, as that'd require the query to read the document which would result in a charge. Loading that specific document on demand would be the way to go, although I'm not fully sure why you'd want to exclude it from the query results. My logic normally is that when the doc falls out of the query results, I don't inspect the snapshot further, but remove the doc from the UI.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I  just implemented the solution to remove the document from client state and ui when `change.type === "removed"` and everything seems to be working fine. Thank you so much for your help!